# Nearby stores ,without using Geo packages, Django Rest

Tags: python, django, annotate

I need to list stores nearby an address
Here is  my code :

```
class Shop(TimeStamp):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CITIES, blank=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, max_digits=10, verbose_name='latitude', default=None)
    long = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, max_digits=10, verbose_name='longitude', default=None)
   
    def distance_shop(self, location):
        return distance((self.lat, self.long), location)
```

#####################

```
    #this is the function I used for calculating distance I used haversine distance(origin, destination)
    def distance(origin, destination):
        lat1, lon1 = origin
        lat2, lon2 = destination
        radius = 6371  # km
        dlat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
        dlon = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)
        a = math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) +      math.cos(math.radians(lat1))* math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2)*math.sin(dlon / 2)
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
        d = radius * c
        return d
```

in my apiView using post method receiving an address lat and long I did this :

```
 class NearbyShops(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = NearbyShopsSerializer

    def post(self, request):
       data = request.data
       serializer = NearbyShopsSerializer(data=data)
       if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
          try:
            address = DeliveryAddress.objects.get(client=request.user, lat=serializer.data.get('address_lat'),
                                                  long=serializer.data.get('address_long'))
          except DeliveryAddress().DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "This address doesn't exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)       

          try:
            shops = Shop.objects.filter(city=address.city)
          except Shop().DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "No shops in this city address"},
                            status=status.HTTP_417_EXPECTATION_FAILED)
          list = {}
          for shop in shops:
             location = (address.lat, address.long)
             dis = shop.distance_shop(location)
             shops = shops.annotate(distance=dis).order_by('distance')
          closest = Shop.objects.filter(distance__lt=10.0)
          for close in closest:
            list['name'] = close.name
            list['long'] = close.long
            list['lat'] = close.lat
          return Response({'shops': list}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I don't know why , but I get in return this error :

QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 4783.728105194982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to store a geopoint in your table rather than storing longitude and latitude separately. This will improve the performance of your view and simplify your code

your Shop, Address model should look like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model:
    geopoint = GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you can use something like this in your view:

```
geopoint = Point(address_long, address_lat)
closest_shops = Shop.objects.filter(geopoint__distance_lte=(place.geometry, D(m=10.0)).annotate(distance=Distance('geometry', geopoint))
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: I wish I could use geopoint and all postgis tools but I can't , I must use latitude and longitude seperately that's what I'm receiving from the client endpoint. I appreciate your help , thank you!

Comment: most DBs have support for spatial queries, so try t do that. I also want to highlight that yu can build the point from what are you getting from the client as shown in my slution

Answer (score 1):

first of all while you try to make geolocation app you should use `postgresql` and its `postgis` extension , and django has a powerful package named [`geodjango`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/) , you dont need anymore use two different field name as you did `long`, `lat`

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Shop(models.Model):
    city= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    long_lat = models.PointField()
```

then inside your views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr , Point
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from .models import Shop


Latitude = 31.2551 # for example , you can get long and lat from user using js
Longitude = 49.8824 #for example
user_location = Point(Latitude , Longitude , srid=4326)

class NearestShop(generic.ListView):
    model = Shop
    context_object_name = 'shops'
    queryset = Shop.objects.annotate(distance=Distance('long_lat ',user_location)).order_by('distance').distinct('distance')
```

if you use windows and cant configure `postgis` i courage you use ubuntu command line on windows

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in my caseI caan't use pstgis at all. I know so well how hoelpful geodjango is but I only have to do geo calcul myself,

Comment: so use the query i have written

Comment: ur query needs the import of gis , and I'm not able to do it requires many libraries that will slow my app

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this instead of using annotate(distance).
without using Postgis extension.

```
       #### see code in Question
        list = {}
        location = (address.lat, address.long)
        for shop in shops:
            dis = shop.distance_shop(location)
            if dis <= 10.0:
                list['name'] = shop.name
                list['long'] = shop.long
                list['lat'] = shop.lat
            return Response({'message': 'no close shops to your address'}, status=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
        return Response({'shops in district': list}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```